# MS Word protected view setting

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

When opening a DOCX document from a WebDAV folder (eg https://www.example.com/demo/docstore/, in Windows mapped under the letter Z), MS Word will use the protected view.

Is it possible to somehow set that documents opened from this folder not to use protected view?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. But you can choose to disable the Protected View feature within Excel so that you no longer receive the warning upon opening any Excel file that has been downloaded. In Excel go to File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Protected View, and then uncheck Enabled Protected View for files originating from the Internet. See [Turn off Protected View in Excel to improve performance of opening Excel documents from the SmartVault Drive](https://support.smartvault.com/Other/Knowledge_Base_and_Known_Issues/Turn_off_Protected_View_in_Excel_to_improve_performance_of_opening_Excel_documents_from_the_SmartVault_Drive) for more information.

There is also, in `Trust Center Settings`, a `Macro Setting` that you can use to `Enable All Macros` by default. Be aware that enabling this feature allows potentially dangerous code to run.